# program for measuring time taken to send varying amount of data between two systems over a LAN

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I want to measure time taken to send varying amount of data between two systems over a LAN.

I want to code in C.

Any one has any idea how to go about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make a simple echo client server and measure the time it took from send to reply

functions you'll need `bind` `socket` `listen` `accept` `read` `write`. All the documentation is found in the man pages (2).

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
char buf[1024];
struct sockadd_in host;
/* ... set up params ... */
int connfd = connect(sock, &host)

time_t now = time(NULL);
time_t then = 0;
time_t delta_t = 0;
write(connfd, "hi", strlen("hi"));
read(connfd, buf,1024); 
then = time(NULL);

delta_t = then - now;
```

This is sort of how it should look (rough pseudo/C code)